# Launching Google Play Store Intent not working

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I am trying to launch `Play Store` so that when the user clicks `Rate Us` in the drop down menu that it will load my app in the google market place. So far when user click `Rate Us` in the menu , the app does nothing and there is no information in the logcat.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.About:
    Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;
case R.id.exit:
    finish();
    break;
case R.id.Rate:
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
               Uri.parse("market://details?
 id="+"com.androidsleepmachine.gamble"));
        startActivity(marketIntent);
}
return false;
}
```

All I need is that when the user clicks Rate on the inflated menu that it will load my app in the market place for them to add a rating. the Logcat says that there is no activity to handle intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code in unclear. Also you are not even starting the `Activity`.

This two lines should work perfectly.

```
Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
       Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.androidsleepmachine.gamble"));
startActivity(marketIntent);
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put that to get it to work? under the Rate.class I should only have that code?

Comment: Put it inside on click of `Rate button`

Comment: I do not have a button exactly for Rate. I have a menu inflater and rate is one of the options. I put that code under the switch for when R.id.Rate is clicked but it does not work

Comment: It should work. Try to debug if option item selected is called. Post the updated code. Will look at it tomorrow morning

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code when click on Rate button

```
final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName(); 
try {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
    }
```